# How can i check paypal personal account or business account?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

i have client's paypal A/C details. I can accessing this account but i could't identify account type. is it Business account or Personnel Account.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to [paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com), click on "Profile" in the top right, then select "Profile and Settings". When the page loads up, click on "My Settings" in the left nav. At the top of the page you should see an account type.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)